# How to replace fillna for categories with column names?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame, I want to fill missing categories with 'colname_miss' string.

```
def FillCatMissing(df):
    cols = ['A','B','C']
    df[cols] = df[cols].fillna('miss')
    return df
```

This fills all missing categories with string 'miss', I need to be like 'A_miss' for column A, 'B_miss' for column B....

Comment: Add the appropriate tag if this is related to pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col].fillna(col+'_miss', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not `apply` with `replace`:

```
def FillCatMissing(df):
    cols = ['A','B','C']
    df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.replace(np.nan, x.name + '_miss'))
    return df
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=['a', None], B=[None, 'b'], C=[None, None]))

df

      A     B     C
0     a  None  None
1  None     b  None
```

---

#### Pass a `dict` to `fillna`

Pandas has a specific way to handle this problem.  Instead of looping over columns and filling each one individually, you can pass a dictionary to the `fillna` method that defines what to replace null values with for each column.  In other words, this is the way it should be done.

In this case, you want the dictionary's keys to match the column names to be filled.

```
df.fillna({k: f'{k}_miss' for k in df})  # This is the answer you are looking for

        A       B       C
0       a  B_miss  C_miss
1  A_miss       b  C_miss
```

We could've left it to just the columns `'A'` and `'B'`

```
df.fillna({k: f'{k}_miss' for k in ['A', 'B']})

        A       B     C
0       a  B_miss  None
1  A_miss       b  None
```

And this leaves column `'C'` alone.

Lastly, this produces a copy with the results rather than mutating the existing dataframe.  If you want to overwrite the existing dataframe then just assign to the the same name

```
df = df.fillna({k: f'{k}_miss' for k in df})
```

---

And though I clearly like the other answer better, this is another way to do it.

```
df.fillna(df.columns.to_series().add('_miss'))

        A       B       C
0       a  B_miss  C_miss
1  A_miss       b  C_miss
```